# Invalid column name 'valor de campo'

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Estoy hace horas intentando hacer una consulta muy simple a la base de datos sql. Trayendo 3 datos en caso de encontrar una coincidencia. El tema es que quizá sea algo que no veo, pero me da un error que no tiene sentido.
Las columnas en sql se llaman Usuario y Clave, como dejo acá abajo. Hago la misma consulta desde sql y me trae los datos sin problema. Pero cuando lo corro desde VS, me da un error que pongo abajo del código. **¿Será algo que no estoy viendo?**
El error me dice que no encuentra las columnas "Admin" y el resto es la clave.. pero entiendo que no estoy buscando columnas que se llamen como el valor de cada campo.
¿Hay algún " o algo que no estoy haciendo correctamente?

Aclaración: Lo rehice unas 5 veces a todo este método, pero el error persiste.
¿Podrían guiarme?
Vi otras preguntas, pero no se asimilan a este error en si.

```
public Empleados VerificarClaveEnBdd(Empleados empleados, Tipos_Empleados _tiposEmpleados)
    {
        string query = @"select Empleados.Usuario, Empleados.Clave, Tipos_Empleados.Tipo
                        from Empleados
                        inner join Tipos_Empleados
                        on Empleados.Tipo_Empleado_ID = Tipos_Empleados.Tipo_Empleado_ID
                        where Exists (select Empleados.Usuario, Empleados.Clave from Empleados 
                        where Empleados.Usuario =  " + empleados.Usuario + " and Empleados.Clave = "+ empleados.Clave + ")"

        ;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);

        try
        {
            OpenConnection();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                _tiposEmpleados.Tipo = Convert.ToString(reader["Tipo"]);
                empleados.Usuario = Convert.ToString(reader["Usuario"]);
                empleados.Clave = Convert.ToString(reader["Clave"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error al tratar de verificar datos", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        return empleados;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y consultando la base de datos, por las dudas, si están los datos que estoy buscando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que te faltan las comillas simples. Por ejemplo si empleados.Usuario es string debes colocar la comillas (debes fijarte bien, porque no se aprecia el cambio a simple vista)   where Empleados.Usuario =  '" + empleados.Usuario + "'

Comment: Yusseff!!! tenés toda la razón. Como había hecho otro método y había funcionado sin las comillas simples, no lo había tenido en cuenta. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Conoces a Bobby Tables? https://bobby-tables.com/ .Tu código es vulnerable a SQL Injection. Deberías usar consultas parametrizadas

Comment: Jesús, muchas gracias!!! No estoy teniendo mucho en cuenta la seguridad, xq estoy haciendo un trabajo práctico para la universidad, pero ya que me lo enseñaste, lo voy a investigar para implementarlo. Desde ya, muchas gracias hermano!!!

Comment: El esfuerzo adicional para parametrizar consultas es mínimo y sus beneficios lo valen. Es bueno que desde un inicio te acostumbres a hacerlo para que no desarrolles malas prácticas de desarrollo.

Comment: Justo pensaba en eso, el tema de no interiorizar malas prácticas. de desarrollo. Muchas gracias por el aporte, porque no me lo habían dicho nunca respecto a sql. Así que desde ahora lo comienzo a implementar en mis prácticas. Muchas gracias!!!